# Method of downloading lots of files sequentially

Tags: windows, command-line, download

I have a text file with several hundred URLs to files that need to be downloaded. Rather than do them all one by one, I was wondering if there's some way to take that list and just download them all for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) can import a list of files from a text file. On Linux for sure you can do something similar with wget.

A better alternative would be [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/), a multi-platform efficient download manager which can automatically download links copied to the clipboard.

Comment: wget works on windows too!

Answer (score 1):

And if you talking about downloading automatically rapidshare, hotfile type files then you can go for [Freerapid downloader](http://wordrider.net/freerapid/)

which can download from a tons of such file sharing websites

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of download manager, but Flashget is one of the oldest.
http://www.flashget.com/index_en.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a little unorthodox (no command line or standalone installation) but I've written a browser extension to Chrome to do just this using Google Chrome's download API - will work across all platforms (operating systems) i.e. Windows/Mac/Linux.

It's called TabSave and originally it was for this, I'm adding the ability to do some things researchers might want to do with giving PDFs titles straight from the browser but it's very light and can grab from open tabs if that's handy.

[You can get the extension here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-save/lkngoeaeclaebmpkgapchgjdbaekacki), and all the code is open source on GitHub [here](https://github.com/lmmx/tabsave).

Feel free to fork if it might be more useful with different scripting :-)

Answer (score 0):

[wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) is surely one of the best.  Available on windows as part of [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).  Tons of features.  A couple key ones:

- command line
- can specify user agent
- can download using list of urls in a file
- can specify wait random time between downloads